# Advance sql query

Tags: sql, join

How to build sql query in this situation:

I have to tables (only showing table columns)

Table one

```
- Users -> ID, First name, Last name....
```

Table two

```
– events -> ID, UserID, statID
```

I want to get sql results like this:

```
ID,
First name,
Last name,
count(from table event where stat == 11 and (between date1 and date2)), 
count(from table event where stat =? 8 and (between date1 and date2))
```

Please help me

Comment: Not all these columns appear in the table descriptions you've provided. Can you please include your actual table descriptions?

Comment: Also what database management system are you using ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a sql server based solution:

```sql
SELECT u.ID, 
       u.[First Name],
       u.[Last Name],
       SUM(CASE WHEN e.statID = 11 AND e.date >= date1 AND e.date<= date2 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) AS CountStat11, 
       SUM (CASE WHEN e.StatID= 8 AND e.date >= date1 AND e.date<= date2 
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS CountStat8
FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN events AS e ON u.ID = e.userid
GROUP BY u.ID, u.[First Name], u.[Last Name]
```

Here I used a `LEFT JOIN` to give you results for all users even if they didn't have any event. If you interested only in those with event id then you need to use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You should point out that this is SQL Server syntax.  The question doesn't specify a database, but the square braces are specific to T-SQL.  It would also be nice to include table aliases on all the columns, but that's a quibble.  And, the question if vague, but the OP might want a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. I updated my answer to cover the issues that you mentioned.

Comment: As a note, the only "SQL Server"ish part of the solution is the use of square braces.  With the appropriate column names, this should run in any database.